# Why is this if statement always true when it shouldn't be?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game where the goal is to get pairs of 4 using a normal card deck. When I prompt for which card value the player wants to ask another player, the `else if (playerArray[turn].cards.indexOf(card) == -1)` ALWAYS evaluates to true, even when the card variable contains a value of the cards array. This makes no sense to me at all and I'm stuck on how to fix this. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

```
var playerArray = [];       //Holds the player objects
var turn = 0;               //Keeps track of whose turn it is
var wrongCard = true;
var card = askCard(player); //Prompt to get a card value

function askCard(player) {

    var whichCard = prompt('The deck has: ' + deck.length + ' cards left in it.\n'
    + 'Your current cards are: ' + playerArray[turn].cards.join(' - ') + '\n'
    + player + ', all your:');

    return whichCard;
}

    while (wrongCard) { //Run as long as the card input is wrong

        if (card < 1 || card > 13) { //If card value is not between 1-13
            card = askCard(player);
        }

        //If the asked card doesn't exist in the current player's cards array
        else if (playerArray[turn].cards.indexOf(card) == -1) { //ALWAYS TRUE, WHY?
            card = prompt('The deck has: ' + deck.length + ' cards left in it.\n' +
                          'Your current cards are: ' + playerArray[turn].cards.join(' - ') 
                          + '\n' + player + ', all your:');
        }

        else {
            wrongCard = false; //Jump out of loop
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the code that puts something in `playerArray[turn]`?

Comment: `console.log(playerArray[turn].cards.indexOf(card));` what does this yield?

Comment: Try to `console.dir(playerArray[turn].cards)` and `console.log(card)` to make sure you know what you are getting.

Comment: @SterlingArcher -1 is what I'm getting, but why I do not know..

Comment: What have you stored in the cards array, numbers or strings? You are now trying to find a string in the array. I guess numbers and you are trying to find a string.

Comment: It is impossible for us to know either if you don't show the contents of the array.

Comment: @Barry I'm storing numbers.

Comment: @Juhana, card is a number between 1-13. The playerArray contains an array called 'cards' which holds a certain number of numbers.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].indexOf("2") === -1`. You're comparing numbers with a string so the result can never be anything other than -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
playerArray[turn].cards.indexOf(parseInt(card,10)) == -1)
```

Comment: If the cards are stored as a string, why are you re-stringing it? It's not wise to answer unclear questions, as assumptions can often be way wrong.

Comment: You should really be doing `parseInt(card, 10)`.

Comment: `parseInt` isn't going to help. Since the problem is that it's always `true`, then that means the `==` is always giving a successful numeric conversion.

Comment: @squint No, it means that it never finds the card. When looking for a string in an array of numbers you will never find it. Result => -1.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I have changed my answer according to your remark. Thanks!

Comment: What does the , 10 do?

Comment: It states that the string contains a value of the decimal system. F.i. parseInt("A", 16) returns 10 because A has a value of 10 in the hexadecimal system.

Comment: What's the difference between not passing ,10 and passing it? Because without it, it seems to work just the same. Can it lead to strange bugs?

Comment: It is advised to do so. Otherwise JavaScript is going to guess what it is. F.i. "01" can be either octal or decimal.